# Photo with landscape orientation like first in the gallery

Tags: laravel, image

My users can add photos to their gallery. I want that like a first will display photo with landscape orientation or the widest (it will be better). I don't care about sort. I wrote only about first photo in gallery.

Answer (score 0):

try intervention/image package
for orientation use this code

```
// import the Intervention Image Manager Class

use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
$img = Image::make('foo.jpg')->orientate();
```

Comment: please visit this link 
[image orientation ,resize](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

Comment: I have read this article but I don't want to change this img but I want to dispay in gallery img with ladscape oritnation like a first.